# Opening file/folder using Windows file dialog in VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

When I try to open file or folder in VsCode, Windows file dialog doesn't open. Instead, a box appears in the top-middle of VsCode to open file/folder.

[image]

How can I use Windows file dialog again?

Comment: opposite question is [here](/q/70267366/11107541)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows file dialog is default to open file/folder. But somehow I changed it to simple one. If you want to use "Simple Dialog" you should add the following lines to `settings.json`:

```
"files.simpleDialog.enable": true
```

To get back Windows file dialog, remove that line or change `true` to `false`.