# Is it possible to get a combined open folder/open file dialog in VSCode when using the simple file dialog?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Using the [simple file dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61038052/opening-file-folder-using-windows-file-dialog-in-vscode) on MacOS allows me to use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to open *either a file or a folder*.

But on Linux (or Windows), I have to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> → <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> if I want to open a folder, or just <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to open a single file. This is frustrating, and I always forget it when I jump from my MacOS work-machine to my personal Linux machine.

On Linux, it looks like this for files:
[image: Open file dialog on Linux]

Since this is a VSCode in-application dialog (*not an operating system dialog*), there shouldn't be any operating system limitations to it.

Is there any option to enable the MacOS-style combined behavior for it?

Comment: I think Windows doesn't let you open a file OR folder in the same window in ANY program.  
On Linux you would have to change the vscode source code and make it behave like you want but it is doable.

Comment: The "simple file dialog" which is I am using works entirely within VSCode, it's not a system dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it was much simpler than I thought.

There is a keybinding for this, it is simply called "File: Open" under "Keyboard shortcuts", and its full name is `workbench.action.files.openFileFolder`.

It currently has the when-constraint `isMacNative && openFolderWorkspaceSupport`, but you can simply remove this by right-clicking the binding, and selecting "Edit When Expression".

Then simply bind it to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> or whatever you desire.